# Errors if free() is called after malloc() in C++

Tags: c++, memory, malloc

I allocate space for array I call test, which will have (2*n + 1) elements of type double. I populate the array, and finally I free() it. But if I use free(), I get an error: "double free or corruption(out): 0x0000000000000f1dc20". If I comment free(), the code runs. I cannot spot the issue.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

long    n=512; //grid size
double *test;

int main() 
{
    test = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * (2*n+1));

    for (long j=-n;j<=n;j++)
    {
        test[j] = double(j);
    }

    free(test); //<--- gives me error if I use this
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This is quite a blend of c and c++. In c++ you should use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`. Even then, prefer containers and `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` over `new`/`delete`. Additionally, c headers are included using the prefix letter c, such as `#include <cstdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: You can't be using negative indices here.

Comment: You should avoid `malloc`/`free` in C++.  `new`/`delete` is the C++ way for manual memory allocations.  That said, `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, or `std::shared_ptr` should be preferred.

Comment: You can only write to `test[0]` up to `test[2*n]`. You write out of bound with `j =-n`. Don't violate the programs constraints, and it won't break.

Comment: Also, You don't test if null pointer is returned by `malloc`

Comment: Wat language are you coming from?!

Comment: I see. I have been using a Numerical Recipes library, which allows me to allocate memory in a similar way to malloc() with a function called dvector(). After allocation, I am able to populate that array by looping from -nr to nr, like I have shown above. I guess with malloc() I cannot do that.

Comment: [Don't use Numerical Recipes](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/wnnr/nr.html) There are any number of modern libraries now available that for practical work are better in performance, language, and numerics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that will just not do.

You allocate enough space for an 2n array of doubles, but C defines the array indices ranging [0..2n-1].  You cannot arbitrarily decide to access the elements with [-n..+n].  As already described in comments, it's **Undefined Behavior**.

If you need to do what you seem to be doing, you will have to use an offset for all the accesses, eg:

```
test[j+n] = double(j);
```

You then stand a much better chance of not destroying your heap structure and so getting annoying error messages from your C and/or OS memory manager.